# Swap MTB parts to road bike

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, compatibility

I have changed my tires to road and crank set to 48 teeth. The question is with all my current parts is there a way I can buy a road bike frame and transfer everything on to the road bike frame?

My MTB is running disk brakes, not a V-brakes.

Comment: Thank you so much Klaster_17 . Yeah it have cross my mind about the bars. I have change my sits and paddles to light weight MTB but some how. nothing like a road bike.

Comment: "Sits and paddles" does not sound like a bike part to me. Using a dictionary could help making the text more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

What's the wheel size? If it's 700c, then you can get disc road/CX/gravel frame. Do mind type of bottom bracket, hub widths and seatpost diameter, though. You can fit MTB shifters and brake levers to a drop bar, but that would look funky, so probably flat bar only. For proper fit, stem might require replacement too.

Comment: is it possible to have MTB derailleurs with road shifters? Assuming the number of the speed is identical.

Comment: It depends on the number of speeds. The rears will be fine for <9 speed, front needs to match mountain/road on Shimano. For >9 speed, there are a bunch of cases, so you can look up the cable pull tables.

Answer (score 2):

Its almost always more cost effective to sell the existing bike and use the funds to buy a (used) bike you want. Its worth doing it from the perspective of learning about bikes, owning a unique piece of art/engineering "franken bike" or just a cool way to kill some spare time. Doing it because you want a road bike and only have a MTB is the wrong reason.

Little things like wrong length cables and chains, incompatibly betwen bottom brackets (chain line problems) can quickly add up to a lot of $$$. If you want drop bars you need road shifters that are not compatible with MTB derailleurs meaning some big ticket items.

Comment: Just call and check with a local bike shop. said the same thing plus hubs and shifters as well. rely need to consider on cost as well. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain degree of compatibility, but usually it comes with a big compromise, such as having to use a flat handlebar (for your MTB shifters and brakes), smaller diameter wheels (road is 28", your MTB is likely 26"), lower gearing (pedaling on road is easier so gears are higher) or bigger than usual tires (because of your wide MTB rims).

By the time you found a road frame that supports discs and bought all the non inter-changeable components you will see it's not worth it.

If you are really really interested in doing this you can post a few pictures of your current MTB and the kind of bike you are looking for and we can help you component by component, but trust me, you will end up getting a road bike.